# Secure communication between two hosted dedicated servers?

Tags: sql-server, replication, dedicated-server

I'm planning to host a site on a pair of dedicated servers (both running IIS/SQL Server with SQL replication). Since the hoster only provides a public IP on each machine, how would I secure replication between the two?

Comment: Just a reminder: "Private" (RFC1918) IP addresses do not equal security.

Answer (score 2):

> Since the hoster only provides a public IP on each machine, how would I secure replication 
>   between the two?

Eve heard of IPSEC? IPSEC can be used to encrypt traffic according to specific rules - so you can set things up on the operating system level that all traffic between those two hosts is encrypted.

You can use a standard VPN.

You can actually get a at least semi-professional host (not having an option for a private network is seriously unprofessional).

You can use standard SQL Server measures to set up encryption for the replication connection (yes, sql server cna do that out of the box).

Answer (score 1):

Not really the best phrased question, but it made me think of a number of approaches.

- Your hosting provider may be able to provide (at an additional charge) private interconnects, i.e. additional switch ports to create a private network on the secondary NIC's of your servers.
- If your servers will be in the same cabinet a simple cross cable can achieve the same.
- In case those aren't options your remaining options are to either encrypt the traffic at the application layer (use SSL/TLS) or
- Create a VPN

Comment: What would be the benefit of setting up a VPN vs. SSL?

Comment: Setting up SSL or TLS is something you need to set up for each application separately where with a VPN all network traffic would be encrypted, regardless of the protocols used.